# How to correctly import 3D max files into Unity3d?

Tags: unity

I am trying to import a downloaded 3D max (.3DS) object into Unity3D and preserve the textures correctly. I've tried to select the .3DS-file and its jpg-files and dragged and dropped it into Unity3D. Everything works fine, and the object can be added to the scene. But I am unable to add the texture to the object. I have tried to drag and drop it like you can do with other kinds of objects, but it won't work on the imported objects.

Comment: This is another way. you can use modeling application like 3ds max, blender to import .3ds file. And export it into fbx file. Then you can import it in Unity easily.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to apply a texture to a Mesh in Unity is creating a **Material** and then assigning your texture to the Albedo/Color map attribute of the Material, then you can drag and drop the Material into your desired Mesh/Object in the Scene.

Material Inspector in Unity 5:

[image: Unity 5. Marked Albedo map in Standard Material]

Cheers!